# Zeros of a seminorm

Tags: vector-spaces

Let us assume that $p$ is a seminorm in a vector space $V$.

Is it possible that there existed $x_1,x_2 \in V$, such that $x_1\neq x_2$ and $p(x_1)=p(x_2)=0$
?

Could you propose such example of seminorm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, take $p((x,y)) = |x|$ for all $(x,y)\in V=\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Of course; in fact setting $\rho(x)=0$ for all $x$ makes $\rho$ a seminorm.

Not only is it possible, it happens for *every* seminorm that's not a norm! Say $\rho$ is a seminorm but not a norm. There exists $x\ne 0$ with $\rho(x)=0$. Hence $x\ne  2x$ and $\rho(x)=0=\rho(2x)$.

Comment: The seminorm $\rho\equiv0$ is pathological but convincing. :-) The second remark is kind of pointless, though, since the OP basically asks about the existence of seminorms that aren't norms.